# Can anybody shed some light on the importance of the notion of compatibility of products of lattices in quaternion algebras?

Tags: quaternions, noncommutative-algebra, ideal-class-group

I have started to study the theory of orders in quaternion algebras, but I am very new to the topic. In particular I am interested in the Class set associated with an order in such an algebra. I have been trying to make parallels with classical algebraic number theory which I am much more familiar with, and to see what changes and what stays the same in this non-commutative setting.

In particular I am trying to get intuition for why the compatibility of lattices is an interesting notion. I understand how products of compatible lattices $I$ and $J$ are a special case of the tensor-products of $\mathcal{O}$-modules, where $\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_l(J) = \mathcal{O}_R(I)$, as the map $i \otimes j \mapsto ij$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}$-modules in this setting. In the end though, even when considering only products of compatible lattices, one fails to obtain a group structure on the ideal class set $Cls \mathcal{O}$. Even in the nice case where $\mathcal{O}$ is maximal, so that every fractional (say left) $\mathcal{O}$-ideal is invertible things do not work out. For this reason, I fail to understand why one should bother to restrict the attention to compatible lattices in the first place. Any kind of insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look at normal ideals with respect to proper (what you call compatible) products, you get a Brandt gruppoid (or groupoid if you prefer).  Classically this was used to study partial composition laws on associated quadratic forms.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Kimball. However, I am not sure I know what you mean by normal ideal. My language comes mostly from the book by John Voight titled Quaternion Algebras. This book also mentions that some authors use the word proper referring to fractional (say left) $\mathcal{O}$-ideals whose left order coincides with $\mathcal{O}$ . I did not know it could be used as a synonym for compatible. I am still not sure I see what properties of a grouppoid one loses in considering non compatible products though.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. Multiplication needs not be well defined, since, for right classes for example $$[I\alpha J] = [I][\alpha J] = [I][J] = [IJ]$$ but the class of $I\alpha J$ is not the same as that of $IJ$ unless one assumes compatibility.

Comment: By normal ideals I mean ideals of maximal orders.  Multiplication of arbitrary ideals makes sense, but it doesn't behave as nicely.  E.g., the product of integral ideals might not be integral.  So if you want to factor an ideal into a product of maximal ideals, you should work with compatible products.  Re your second comment: even for compatible products, multiplication isn't well defined on ideal classes---that's why you get a groupoid and not a group.

Comment: Thank you @Kimball, everything is much clearer now.